# How to get all running default values of systemd system.conf?

Tags: systemd

We could list all running default values of kernel parameters with `sysctl -a`.

Is there a way to list all running default values of systemd system.conf as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
systemctl show
```

This will show all available properties.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/systemctl.1.html